# I am a newbie and i don't understand why this error keeps occurring...please help me out

Tags: python, csv

**ERROR:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mathew/Desktop/Python/PROJECT PRGRMS/defo.py", line 1, in <module>
    import csv
  File "C:/Users/Mathew/Desktop/Python/PROJECT PRGRMS\csv.py", line 7, in <module>
    with open(csv_path,"rb") as f_obj:
NameError: name 'csv_path' is not defined
```

**CODE:**

```
import csv

with open('emp.csv','w') as emp_file:
    w=csv.writer(file,delimiter=',')
    w.writerow(['Jane Thomas', 'Accounting', 'November'])
    print('RECORD WRITTEN SUCCESSFULLY')
    enter code here
```

Comment: You appear to have posted only one of the two files.

Comment: sorry i just began to post i am still trying to figure out how this works thanks for editing...

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is you have a `csv.py` in your working directory, and Python imports it instead of the standard library `csv` module, which you mean to use.

Your `csv.py` itself has that name error.

Rename `csv.py` to e.g. `csv_test.py` and you're good to go.

Answer (score 2):

You've named one of your files "csv.py" which means that when you do `import csv` you import that file rather than the `csv` module from the standard lib.